# NSInvalidArgumentException: expected Dictionary but actual _SwiftDeferredNSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, bridging

I'm working on a ReactNative application with native dependencies. Particularly I'm trying to link iOS xcframework of a proprietary library. I can build an application and init SDK but in a couple of moments after it, the app crashes because the SDK is trying to send an analytics but fails.

The error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "data"; desired type = Dictionary; given type = _TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSSS_$; value = {
    "app_type" = MEP;
    "application_bundle_id" = "xxx";
    "application_installer_id" = "com.apple.dt.Xcode";
    "application_name" = xxx;
    "application_version" = "999.999.999";
    "client_id" = "xxx";
    country = xxx;
    "device_platform" = "iPhone16,1|iOS|17.2";
    "external_app_id" = "xxx";
    "mep_analytics_sdk_version" = "1.1.1";
}.'
```

Top of the backtrace:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x110ee6751 __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x116290904 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreData                               0x10f367a7c _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 2175
3   CoreData                               0x10f36f51b _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 177
4   CoreData                               0x10f3737e3 _sharedIMPL_copying_setvfk_core + 54
5   XxxAnalytics                           0x1137d94f5 specialized Client.__allocating_init(entity:insertInto:id:data:) + 229
6   XxxAnalytics                           0x1137e5a13 closure #1 in AnalyticsStorageManager.add(_:) + 355
7   XxxAnalytics                           0x1137daedc thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 12
8   XxxAnalytics                           0x1137daefe thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 14
9   CoreData
```

Where XxxAnalytics is a proprietary lib that I'm linking.

**Investigation:**
When I link the lib to a new ReactNative application (created with `npx react-native@0.71.2 init TestProj`) everything works OK. But when I link it with the production application it crashes. Looks like the issue is in build settings but I don't know where exactly.

The production application doesn't use ReactNative autolinking.

In [Swift sources](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L195)  I've found that `SwiftDeferredNSDictionary` is a Swift-ObjC bridging implementation. So I can assume that in some cases the dictionary is formed in Swift and everything ok but in other cases it is formed in ObjC and it breaks it.

**The question:** what build settings might lead to such an error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by [ReactNative navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) lib. This lib contains a [`Dictionary` interface](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/7.38.1/lib/ios/Dictionary.h) that creates a name collision with the Swift `Dictionary`. Renaming this interface resolves the issue.